# OpenRewrite: Not visiting files from src/main/resources directory

Tags: java, gradle, openrewrite

I am using OpenRewrite recipe org.openrewrite.DeleteSourceFiles to delete some files. But it is not detecting or deleting files from src/main/resources directory or src/test/resources. I have basic gradle java project which have src/main/java src/main/resources src/test/java & src/test/resources directories. I am using gradle plugin of openrewrite to run recipe.

I tried running this recipe in dry run mode with "**" as filePattern just to check what all files it detects. Seems like it does not even detect files from src/main/resources & src/test/resources. It detects files from src/main/java, src/test/java & also some other random directories I have at the root but not resources under main or test. Due to this it doesn't delete it. Not sure what's the issue specifically with resources directories?

Comment: Resources are read-only?

Comment: resources directories are not read only. I am able to open files in those directory & edit it, change it manually. It just that TreeVisitor in openrewrite is not visiting files under resources directory. I am even trying to create custom recipe & even there TreeVisitor is not visiting files under resources.

Comment: Not ultimately read-only no, in the context of development or of course you wouldn't be able to write your app. The point is that when the app is packaged for distribution, that directory and its children *will become* read-only. You can't write to a jar

Comment: The Rewrite gradle plugin does parse resources (and indeed all files in the project whether or not they are in a source set or not): https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-gradle-plugin/blob/main/plugin/src/main/java/org/openrewrite/gradle/isolated/DefaultProjectParser.java#L806

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix for this issue is now available in [rewrite-gradle-plugin 6.8.3](https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-gradle-plugin/releases/tag/v6.8.3) and [rewrite-maven-plugin 5.23.0](https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-maven-plugin/releases/tag/v5.23.0).

Your debugging narrowing the problem to TreeWalk helped to fix this!
I've made [this commit](https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-polyglot/commit/1caa67f3c8481d09234a6126f2e79d161f11fd49) to rewrite-polyglot so that it produces the same list of files-to-parse on Windows as it does on unix-style paths.

Answer (score 1):

OpenRewrite does in fact visit files in `src/main/resources` and indeed every other file whether or not it is in a source directory or not (provided that the file is under the configurable maximum threshold of 10MB).

`DeleteSourceFiles` works as intended as far as I can tell. I will provide the exact setup I used below to test in the hopes that this helps you as well.

### Cloning a repository and adding the Rewrite plugin

I used Steps 1 and 2 [here](https://docs.openrewrite.org/running-recipes/getting-started#step-1-clone-sample-project) to add the Rewrite Gradle plugin to a sample project.

### Create a rewrite.yml

Create a new file rewrite.yml at the root of the repository:

```yaml
---
type: specs.openrewrite.org/v1beta/recipe
name: io.moderne.DeleteApplicationProperties
recipeList:
  - org.openrewrite.DeleteSourceFiles:
      filePattern: '**/application*.properties'
```

### Activate the recipe

In your build.gradle, activate the recipe:

```
rewrite {
  activeRecipe(
    'io.moderne.DeleteApplicationProperties'
  )
}
```

### Run

```
./gradlew rewriteDryRun
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this & it got me some more debugging info. When I just download spring pet project as a zip & run openrewrite it visits resources directory fine. But if I take it as a git repository then it doesn't work. I debugged & found that tree walking is different for git repo vs normal directory in OmniParser.java in openrewrite code. If its git repository then openrewrite has own code to walk tree else it used NIO Files walking feature. NIO walking works fine but when its git repo it did not work. Not sure if this is happening just for me. I am doing this on windows OS in case that matters.

Comment: I did further debugging & found that there seems to be a bug in TreeWalk.java > isPathMatch() code within rewrite. This method rejects "src" directory to traverse for "src/main"/resources" due to some slash character matching. Hence it doesn't visit "/resources" files. This seems like class form JGIT library added inside rewrite code as fat jar. Seems like dead end. Any suggestions?